# Renaming MS-DOS internal commands

Tags: shell, command-line, command-prompt, dos

Is it possible by any means to rename the internal commands of DOS? Firstly, I am doing this to learn a bit about the internals and possibilities of DOS. So far I have changed the internal command CLS to XLX (on Windows XP). But the command name XLX isn't executing. I am attaching 2 screenshots for the reference. Above everything else, this whole activity is just my curiosity.

[image: debugged the command.com file and changed the CLS to XLX] 
[image: debugged the command.com file and changed the CLS to XLX]

Comment: That's not MS-DOS by the way. Hasn't been for quite some time now :-) It may look like it but it's very different under the covers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shell you're running isn't DOS and it isn't `command.com`; as the window title indicates, it's `cmd.exe` which is a different program entirely. Your changes might actually work if you were *running* the DOS command interpreter — which might or might not be as easy as just running `command` from the cmd shell.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have only changed the string containing *documentation* about the CLS command. I would suspect that there is another "CLS" string somewhere.

It is difficult to know for sure because command.com is closed source software. One thing you could do is use debug or another debugger (ollydebug is a free GUI debugger) to trace out what happens when you run CLS and find the conditional jump where command.exe decides to perform the cls command.

Comment: No, it looks like the other *obvious* location is accounted for, in the string table at B426. Of course, it's possible that there's another crucial location in a less-obvious form like `if (*c == 'C' && *(c+1) == 'L' && *(c+2) == 'S')` or similar... but a way bigger concern than that if you ask me is the fact that mjb isn't actually running the code he's modifying.

Comment: @hobbs: yes that is why I upvoted your comment. :) Having said that when reverse engineering closed source software it is usually helpful to investigate all avenues if one avenue is not working.

Comment: @teambob Your answer is certainly leading me to explore in depth. Thanks a lot for the debugging advice.

Comment: @paxdiablo I wasn't bored enough to do this unproductive activity. It was just part of the discussion about exploring the possibilities of DOS command interpreter. Yes hujelabs.com is expired! Since we have moved to a new domain, we didn't actually found it necessary to renew it. I have removed that domain from my profile. About the white coat people, they'll pay a visit if and only if I am diving into the unethical world of hacking/cracking. I am afraid that's not the case. Whatever I have done was part of my personal inquisitiveness. Hope that I have cleared all your concerns :)

Answer (score 0):

COMMAND will try to run CMD's internal commands, at least on Vista.
To see the difference try starting COMMAND, and then the command VER. COMMAND /C VER will give a different result, so if you did it right you should try "COMMAND /C XLX". I have no idea if that will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

changing the internal command mgiht cause danger to yoiur registry content.. so i suggest you to oerform your experiment after having a backup of your data or on a virtual machine is most preferable as per my experience..